# Random svg lines appearing when panning in safari

Tags: svg, safari

I am experiencing two weird things happening with svg rendered in safari (works fine in Chrome/Edge/FF and heck even IE)

1. Lines not defined in SVG will appear and disappear randomly when panning around.
2. Lines defined in SVG might disappear randomly when panning around.

Not really that easy to describe so I made a video for it

https://youtu.be/BqlItab0k_g

I did not use any fancy SVG feature like script or media query. The only elements used are text/path/rectangle.

The SVG is generated by me and optimized using SVGO

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alt22247/pen/vwzBmL)
```

The svg is base64 encoded since I can't upload svg to code pen. Had to use code pen instead of SO built in since the base64 encoded img text exceed SO limit. Feel free to decode it back to text.

I can't think of any way to mess up the SVG without causing a parse error so I believe this is a Safari bug. But we need to support Safari regardless (typical life of a web dev).

So the question is: What is causing this and is there any work around I can do rather than wait for Apple to fix it 10 years later?

Comment: Have you reported it as a webkit bug? The 10 year countdown won't even start till you do that. You could always shortcut the countdown and submit a patch yourself of course, or pay someone else to do so.

Comment: If you have an Apple developer account you can submit a bug here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. If not, I'm happy to submit a bug on your behalf. But in either case, I think providing a simpler SVG would help the engineers isolate the problem. Does the problem occur with an SVG of just a one-room dwelling? Or just a single wall?

Comment: You don't need to be an apple developer, this is almost certainly a bug in webkit rather than Safari: https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/

Comment: @BrettDonald thats the problem. It only happens with SVG of a certain size. small SVGs are all fine. And yea I submitted a dev bug report already. Going to submit another one to webkit i guess